# Scrapy unable to retrieve attribute value using Xpath

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to get hold of the `@src` attribute using xPath but when I ran my scrapy it returns an empty array. Someone please explain to me where did I do wrong?

[Snippet of the HTML code with the attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJoEU.png)

xPath

```
//div[@class='BuC9jaLeEj']//child::div/img[@class='P2llUzsDMi']/@src
```

Using the browser I am able to locate the path to the tag name but when I run my Scrapy bot it return an empty array.

Comment: Just guessing: Maybe your *parser* stumbles upon the `alt` attribute that is lacking its value and already fails to build a (useful) DOM from your HTML.

Comment: It is almost certainly that you are looking at what **Chrome** sees, and not at the page source which is what Scrapy sees. Scrapy will not evaluate JS, so if that `BuC9jaLeEj` does not appear in the page source, you're never going to match it

Comment: @mdaniel you're right about it but how do I parse in the html after evaluating JS?

Comment: Usually if something is loaded dynamically, you're in luck because it means the page is making an API call to pull back just the data, no "scraping" required. Some pages put the data in the HTML themselves, but the majority just us a URL that returns JSON, and that's the thing you'd call from Scapy. Without more specifics about your page, it's hard to provide more actionable advice beyond "that is not a novel problem, there's lots of documentation and examples online"

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score 0):

You might also find this useful:

You can then pick out the image from the dictionary

https://pypi.org/project/chompjs/